# popToViewController: 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

My Secondview is BController *bview.
now in this view there is 1 back button

on click of that back button

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
AController *aview= [[AController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    NSArray *array = [self.navigationController popToViewController: aview animated:YES];

}
```

AController *aview is nothing but my first view or you can say first view

but in click of back button I'm getting exception

** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Tried to pop to a view controller that doesn't exist.'
2010-03-18 15:53:05.948 IChitMe[5072:207] Stack: (
    820145437,
    837578260,
    819694387,
    814928571,
    862794500,
    862794216,
    54911,
    819902607,
    861951876,
    862404412,
    819902607,
    861951876,
    861951724,
    861951668,
    861950732,
    861953932,
    861948160,
    861945748,
    861927312,
    861925524,
    858687888,
    819893547,
    819891231,
    858682228,
    861592624,
    861585968,
    10069,
    9964
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'

Comment: There is a nice tutorial for the German developers: http://bedifferently.wordpress.com/2012/01/15/xcode-4-tutorial-uinavigationcontroller/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

navigationController manages stack of UIViewControllers. It's like stack of cards. When you call one of pop methods:

```
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

you remove some controllers from top, and show corresponding controller:

```
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

pops to first (i.e. lowest in stack) controller, it is called "root".

```
- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
```

pops to specified viewController, and **note it should be already in the stack!**

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

pops to previous controller (below current).

So if you want to show your AController *aview using pop... method of navigationController it should be already in navigationController stack - this is **viewControllers** property of navigationController:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *viewControllers
```

for example:

```
aController = [[AController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
bController = [[BController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:aController]; 
[navigationController pushViewController:bController];
```

now bController is shown and you can call:

```
[navigationController popToViewController:aController animated:YES];
```

Comment: how to take outlet ,property and synthesize of viewControllers

Comment: I used as u tell but i'm getting blank whiteview

Comment: what is this NSArray *viewControllers?

Comment: When I try `[navigationController popToViewController:aController animated:YES];` it said that `aController is undefined`. It make sense since I am in `bController` now, I dont have a reference of `aController`, right? or Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, if you want to pop to definite controller you should have a reference to it. Most common practice to have all necessary references in object accessable from all controllers, for example it can be your application delegate. If you define in MyAppDelegate.h property 
@property (retain) UIViewController * bController;
You can access appdelegete anywhere as MyAppDelegate * appDelegate =(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; And then you can use appDelegate.bController;

Comment: @Vladimir honestly amazing tip. So glad I read that!! Never thought of how to navigate around the view hierarchy like that. What about memory issues though? Does this store an extra view controller in ram?

Answer (score 24):

Use

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

OR

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];
```

Comment: For me self.navigationController.viewControllers always seems to have no contents, even though the screen I use it on is able to pop back several screens via the back button of the navigation controller.

Comment: it seems to me that your view controller is not subclass of uinavigationcontroller

Comment: Great! Worked Flawlessly.